# Query to combine/squash rows in a single table based on id, without making new columns

Tags: sql

Just started learning sql and I'm having trouble with this task.

If I have this table:

| id | pet | color | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog |  |  |
| 1 | dog | blue |  |
| 1 |  |  | 6 |

I want a query that lets me almost just squash these row values. In this table, there will never be column clashes per id. So for id=1, pet will always be dog.

So the query should return:

| id | pet | color | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | blue | 6 |

Edit: blanks are nulls

Comment: One method is using max() for each of those last three columns.

Comment: Are the "blanks" actually NULL or empty strings?

Comment: @Stu blanks are nulls

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate like min or max. Thinking blanks might be whitespace, max would be a better choice:

```
select id, max(pet) as pet, max(color) as color, max(weight) as weight
from myTable
group by id
```

OTOH you should think why you needed to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80bd3bb/1) does the trick, as others have mentioned.

```sql
    SELECT id,
           MAX(pet)    pet,
           MAX(color)  color,
           MAX(weight) weight
      FROM tbl
     GROUP BY id
```

But, as a guy who wrangles a lot of fairly dirty data sometimes, this procedure makes me cringe. It's really crude in the way it deals with extra data or contradictory data.

This might work better, because it'll generate easy-to-see irritating results if there's contradictory data.  It's MySQL specific.  [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4347f5a/1).

```sql
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pet    SEPARATOR '--DUPLICATE--')  pet,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT color  SEPARATOR '--DUPLICATE--')  color,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT weight SEPARATOR '--DUPLICATE--')  weight
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY id
```

It will generate results that look like this, highlighting contradictory or duplicate data.

```
| id |  pet |                     color |            weight |
|----|------|---------------------------|-------------------|
|  1 |  dog |                      blue |                 6 |
|  2 |  cat |                    calico |                 3 |
|  3 | bear | grizzly--DUPLICATE--brown | 70--DUPLICATE--30 |
```

Both these formulations use a particular feature of SQL. Aggregate functions (MAX and GROUP_CONCAT here) ignore NULL values.